# Loading images from jars for Swing HTML

Tags: java, html, image, swing

While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127/java-swing-displaying-images-from-within-a-jar) works to load images from Jar files for `ImageIcons`, I cannot seem to get the right path for images referenced in [Swing HTML](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).

This displays an image in the Swing HTML when the resources are not bundled into a jar:

```
new JLabel("<html><table cellpadding=0><tr><td><img src='file:icons/folder_link.png'></td></tr><tr><td>100</td></tr></table></html>") );
```

Inside of the jar, the image can be successfully referenced (and displayed) into an `ImageIcon`:

```
Icon topIcon = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("icons/folder_link.png" ) );
```

However, my attempt to use the `getResource` technique for Swing HTML doesn't work.

```
String p = getClass().getResource("icons/folder_link.png" ).getPath();
new JLabel("<html><table cellpadding=0><tr><td><img src='" + p + "'></td></tr><tr><td>100</td></tr></table></html>") );
```

What's the secret?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Without actually having tried it, I would assume that the HTML renderer can access your image if you include the resource URL in your HTML code:

```
String p = getClass().getResource("icons/folder_link.png" ).toString();
new JLabel("<html><table cellpadding=0><tr><td><img src='" + p + "'></td></tr><tr><td>100</td></tr></table></html>") );
```

Comment: Also, _don't forget to wrap the url in apostrophes_ (like me). Strangely enough, without apostrophes it worked in eclipse but not when bundled in a jar.

Answer (score 9):

**URL is the secret**

Try this mate:

```
URL p = getClass().getResource("icons/folder_link.png" );
new JLabel("<html><table cellpadding=0><tr><td><img src='" + p + "'></td></tr><tr><td>100</td></tr></table></html>") );
```

Then you could also do this:

```
Icon topIcon = new ImageIcon(p);
```

and then set this icon as the icon for your JLabel if you want to do that!

Comment: Your answer converts the URL object toString().

Answer (score 6):

Answer expanded and moved to [Is it possible/how to embed and access HTML Files in a JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18443315/418556)

Answer (score 0):

Because even the [original demo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ButtonHtmlDemoProject/src/components/ButtonHtmlDemo.java) from Sun for using HTML in Swing does not embed the images in HTML (for generating buttons *with* image icons), I doubt that there is even support for displaying images in place. I remember reader "limited subset of HTML" somewhere, but can't find a reference right now.

Edit: *Please see Andrew's comment and answer, it really works.*

Comment: "I doubt that there is even support for displaying images in place." While the `JEditorPane` will only display a limited sub-set of HTML with simple CSS - you are way off track there.  See my example.