# JCheckbox: add icon from jar not a directory to label?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jcheckbox

I know it's possible to use HTML but what if you are loading the icon image from a package instead of a directory?

How would you go about adding icon to a jcheckbox's label?

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing/checkbox_AddIcon.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `Icon` and `String` to the `JLabel`, then set [JLabel#setLabelFor(myJCheckBox)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setLabelFor%28java.awt.Component%29)

Answer (score 3):

I show various ways in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6373907/418556) to "Loading images from jars for Swing HTML".  But using an explicit URL (obtained from `Class.getResource(String)`) should work just fine as the `src` attribute of the `img` element.

Comment: @mKorbel It was interesting, but I think yours is the better answer on this thread. :)