# How to use getResource() to load an image and some html files?

Tags: java, html, jar, embedded-resource, getresource

In eclipse I made a project inside the `src` folder. I made a package called `res` inside it I put all of the `html`/`gif` files.

Can someone please give me the line of code that would change button with the new location?

```
setIcon(new ImageIcon("Back24.gif"));
```

Can also please provide an example of doing the same thing with an HTML file called `index.html` in the same location as the icon?

```
htmlPane.setPage("file:\\" +path +"\\Contents.html");
```

I would also like to ask if I create a jar with all of these resource files inside and I take that jar to another PC would it still find and load these resource?

Comment: Would you also like some coffee and donuts with that code?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373621/loading-images-from-jars-for-swing-html/6373907#6373907) for examples.

Comment: `"file:\\" +path +"\\Contents.html"` is ***not*** a valid URL.  Try forming a file, check that it exists, then print the result of `file.toURI().toURL()` to see the mistake.