# How to display image in JEditorPane from local filesystem?

Tags: java, html, image, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to display an image in a `JEditorPane` in a Java Swing window. The user uses a `JFileChooser` to find the absolute path of an image on their computer, and then that absolute path is embedded into an HTML `<img>` tag, which is then set in a `JEditorPane`. For some reason, the image will just not show in the `JEditorPane`, and I can't figure out why. I've Googled around and found various solutions, but none have worked. Can someone please help me?

Comment: 1) See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6373907/418556) for general tips. 2) I suspect the code is using a string representing a `File` for the image path, when an `URL` should be used. 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the images in the imageCache of Document like it's described here
http://java-sl.com/tip_local_images.html

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the best method for getting this done.