# use html file from jar in java

Tags: java, swing, executable-jar

I want  to add html files to jar files and access them through jar in the windows application 
project how can i access them 
I am using the following code .

```
   try{
      File f1= new File(getClass.getResource("/path is the src folder/));
     }
```

but it is showing no suitable constructor found

Comment: `File` won't take a `URL` as reference.  Embedded resources like this aren't actually files, they are `InputStream`s to the resource.  Depending on how you're showing them will determine what you need to do.

Comment: If your HTML file is inside your JAR, you cannot access it via a `File` object. You would have to use Java's I/O streams' classes to do this. You should provide more information about what it is exactly that you're trying to do.

Comment: This will work, `File f1 = new File(new URL(getClass().getResource("/path is the src folder/")));`. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) might can give more inputs on the said topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File` won't take a `URL` as reference.  Embedded resources like this aren't actually files, they are `InputStream`s to the resource.

Depending on how you're showing them will determine what you need to do.

For example, `JEditorPane` takes a `URL` via its `setPage` method

**UPDATED**

You should be able to load the pages directly into the editor pane using something like...

```
// editor pane is a reference to a JEditorPane
editorPane.setPage(getClass.getResource("/path is the src folder/"));
```

Comment: Actually i want to add html files in jar and then display them in jeditorpane by using jar file

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6373907/418556) for an e.g. of loading HTML (with styles and images) from a Jar.

Comment: Those docs linked by @trashgod would look fine in a `JEditorPane` if loaded from a Jar.  ;)