# How to get an image to the database, and set it as a "tooltipText()" for the table for a specific row

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, tooltip

I am creating a program that has a JTable on it, populated by my database' data. each row , has a corresponding picture on it, so what i want to happen is that when i set my mouse cursor over that row , it will popUp a tooltipText which contain its picture ,

```
 tblListOfInmates = new JTable(){                       
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 8240878564742150750L;
                public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);                     
                        if (c instanceof JComponent)  {
                            try{
                                    JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;    

                                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");                                                                          
                                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:RIM");
                                    st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

                                    String x = tblListOfInmates.getModel().getValueAt(row, 6).toString();
                                    String sql = "select * from records where ID ='"+x+"'";
                                    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                                    java.net.URL url = new File(rs.getString("ID")).toURI().toURL();





                                     final String html = "<html><body>" + "<img src='"+ url + "' width=160 height=120> ";

                                    jc.setToolTipText(html + "<br/>"
                                            + getValueAt(row, column).toString()
                                            + ":  row, col (" + row + ", " + column + ")");                                     
                            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                        }
                        return c;
                    }
            };
```

I got this error.

```
 at RecordManagementSystem.MainFrame$18.prepareRenderer(MainFrame.java:860)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I dont know how to properly do this, and i dont know if my Idea was right/good. Please tell me if you have a better Idea than this =)

Comment: Is this an actual file in the file system `new File(rs.getString("ID"))`? If not, it won't work.

Comment: Note the html is broken since `</body></html>` is missing at the end of the string you're setting as tool tip text. Also `</img>` close tag is missing. That's probably because you just copy/paste @peeskiltet's code provided in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22246185/1795530) without understand it first.

Comment: Are the images saved in the db as blobs? or are they in the file system?

Comment: @peeskillet , yes , the picture is on the file system .

Comment: @dic19 sorry, because i dont know how to code hmtl , im a newbie XD

Comment: @dens14345 don't be and no need to apologize, but keep in mind it's not a good practice just copy-paste code. It's more important understand what does it do than the code itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the images you have are trying to load in the tool tip are blobs in the db. The problem with this is that a url can't be made from a database object. You *can* have the url stored in the db to a url in the file system, but I think that may be out of the question because you don't want to have images both in the database *and* the file system.

Maybe what you should do is when you're loading the `TableModel`, all the corresponding images, save to the file system (temporarily). You can do that with `File.createTempFile`. You can get a URL from that img.

Also note you'll want to do this in background thread. See [Concurrency with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

You can then access those images from the file system, which will be alot more efficient than trying to access from the db one at a time. You can then use the url from the file system in the html String using `File.getUri().getUrl()`

You can have a method that clears the file system of those images. You might want to call it every time a new set of table data is loaded, and/or when the program closes.

You can load an image from a db blob and write it to file like this

```
Blob blob = rs.getBlob("img");
int blobLength = (int) blob.length();  

byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
blob.free();
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("..."));
```

Here's an example with most of the above mentioned points. Except the background thread. Two lazy for that, but you'll want to do that every time your update your table model from the db

[image]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TableToolTip {

    private Map<String, URL> fileMap;

    public TableToolTip() {
        fileMap = new HashMap<>();
        JTable table = createTable();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JTable createTable() {
        JTable table = new JTable(createModel()) {

            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                if (c instanceof JComponent) {
                    JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
                    URL url = fileMap.get((String) getValueAt(row, column));
                    String html = "<html><body>"
                            + "<img src='"
                            + url
                            + "' width=150 height=150> ";

                    jc.setToolTipText(html + "<br/>"
                            + getValueAt(row, column).toString()
                            + ":  row, col (" + row + ", " + column + ")"
                            + "</body></html>");
                }
                return c;
            }
        };
        return table;
    }

    private DefaultTableModel createModel() {
        DefaultTableModel model = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mario", "root", "password");
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from characters");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData rsMeta = rs.getMetaData();
            String colTitle = rsMeta.getColumnName(1);

            model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{colTitle}, 0);

            while (rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString("NAME");
                model.addRow(new Object[]{name});
                File temp = File.createTempFile(name, ".png");
                Blob blob = rs.getBlob("IMG");
                int blobLength = (int) blob.length();
                byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
                blob.free();
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
                ImageIO.write(img, "png", temp);

                URL fileURL = temp.toURI().toURL();
                fileMap.put(name, fileURL);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return model;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TableToolTip();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: better :-) tommorow, as aside to use util.List instead of HashMap

Answer (score 4):

- every Key and Mouse Events are immediatelly fired inside TableCellRenderer, then exception from RepaintManager is generated from long and heavy JDBC task, don't do that, nor to opening JDBC Connection, there is generated bunch of Key and Mouse Events, especially Mouse Events are per each of pixels
- load all images to local variables as Icon/ImageIcon, event. to the array of Icon/ImageIcon,

Comment: The problem with this is that he needs a url for the tool-tip html

Comment: put rellated Icon/ImageIcon to XxxTableModel, this column can't be visible (remove() from JTables view), then all mouse or key events aer only about convert view index to model and getValueAt, pleas why complicating simple things, did you :-)

Comment: That makes complete sense but the OP wants a tool-tip with the image, which from what I understand can only be done with html. Do you suggest he just ditch the idea about the tool-tip all together?

Comment: not I'm gapping into tablet, but here is code example from Official Oracle tutorial showing How to show JToolTip, but for current cell under the Mouse Cursor (note for un_sorted/filtered JTables view), then there isn't problem to load and Icon/ImageIcon from another column (from XxxTableModel)

Comment: (by using) Html only to help to display any of Image types in Swing JComponents, comfortable and easilly

Comment: Can you provide the link for loading image types in html. I can't seem to find it.

Comment: posts by [Andrew Thompson](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A418556+image+%2B+html), [e.g. one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18443485/714968), sure there must be the same result from posts by MadProgrammer or camickr