# show an image when hover over a jtable cell

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a JTable created with a DefaultTableModel, and I want to show an image when the mouse hovers over a particular cell of that JTable, and I need the image to be different for each cell.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

You can override `prepareRenderer` of the `JTable` and `setToolTip` for the cell/column/row component, and use some HTML for the tooltop, as see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22246185/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22255541/2587435)

[image]

For each different image you will need to get a different URL as the `src` of the `img` tag. You'll need to know some basic HTML for this. You can obtain an URL by using `getClass().getResource()` for images in the class path. Or you can use `File.getUri().getUrl()` to get image files on the file system. One of the links above also shows how you can get images from a relational database.

Whatever way you obtain the URL, you will use it for the URL in the `<img src` tag. Something like (from linked answer):

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/path/to/image");
String html = "<html><body>"
        + "<img src='"
        + url
        + "' width=150 height=150> ";

jc.setToolTipText(html + "<br/>"
        + getValueAt(row, column).toString()
        + ":  row, col (" + row + ", " + column + ")"
        + "</body></html>");
```

You will need to organize your images in some way where you can the data from the model corresponds some way to a path that can used to obtain the URL. Say you have a name as a piece of data in the table, then you want to be able to use that name as an identifier in obtaining the URL

---

**UPDATE** with complete example

Given this is my following project structure

```
ProjectRoot
          src
             resources
                    mario
                         Mario.png
                         Luigi.png
```

the following works

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TableTooltipDemo {

    public TableTooltipDemo() {
        JTable table = getTable(getModel());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table ToolTip");
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JTable getTable(DefaultTableModel model) {
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
                    int row, int col) {

                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
                if (c instanceof JComponent) {
                    JComponent jc = (JComponent)c;
                    String name = getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
                    String html = getHtml(name);
                    jc.setToolTipText(html);
                }   
                return c;
            }
        };
        return table;
    }

    private String getHtml(String name) {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/resources/mario/" + name + ".png");
        String html
        = "<html><body>"
        + "<img src='"
        + url
        + "' width=150 height=150></body></html>";
        return html;
    }

    private DefaultTableModel getModel() {
        String[] cols = { "Name", "Age", "Message" };
        Object[][] data = { { "Mario", 32, "I am Mario!" },
                { "Luigi", 32, "I am Luigi!" },
                { "Bowser", 32, "I am Bowser!" },
                { "Princess", 32, "I am Princess!" },
                { "Koopa", 32, "I am Koopa!" } };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, cols);
        return model;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TableTooltipDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I inderstand how to get an image URL, but I don't know how to use this code, or where to insert it? what is jc ?

Comment: It's a JComponent. You cant set a tooltip on a Component, so first you check if the renderer component is an instance of `JComponent`, then cast it. `jc` is the casted Component to a `JComponent` so that you can call `JComponent`'s `setToolTip` on the renderer component

Comment: Look at the links I posted. They have complete working examples

Comment: See my **UPDATE** for a more intuitive working example. The linked answers may be a little off for what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a custom `TableCellRenderer`.

If you subclass from `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, which extends `JLabel`, you can very easily introduce the images by using the renderer's `setIcon` method, and providing it with one of your images wrapped inside an `ImageIcon`.

If this is your first attempt with renderers, I suggest reading the following tutorial: [Custom table renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to change what is in the cell, I just want the image to be shown when the cursor of the mouse is on the cell

Comment: Do I have to add a listener and apply the renderer inside it ? and how to do so ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to change what is in the cell" ? Do you want the image to appear in a tooltip ?