# Show an image when the mouse hovers over a JTable cell using the prepareRenderer method

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable created using this code :

```
table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
            },
            en_entete
        )
                )

        {
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {

                URL fileURL = null;

                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root", "root");
                    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select name, img from table where id=1");
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        String name = rs.getString("name");
                        File temp = File.createTempFile(name, ".jpg");
                        Blob blob = rs.getBlob("img");
                        int blobLength = (int) blob.length();
                        byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
                        blob.free();
                        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
                        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", temp);

                        fileURL = temp.toURI().toURL();
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                html
                = "<html><body>"
                + "<img src='"
                + fileURL + "'>";

                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                if (c instanceof JComponent) {
                    JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
                    jc.setToolTipText(html);
                }
                return c;
            }

        };
```

So when the mouse hovers over a cell of my JTable, the image show up. But I want that image to be different for each cell (changing the SQL request) and to be shown only for the first column.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1- Use a `TableCellRenderer` over using `prepareRenderer`; 2- The value of the cell should be able to provide the required information to build the query

Comment: Can you please show me how to do so ?

Comment: Not unless you can provide me which your `TableModel`

Comment: I use the defaultTableModel as shown in the code posted

Comment: Which column is used to carry the image identification?

Comment: The first column (index 0)

Comment: -1, you got a working example when you asked this question hours earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23602828/131872. Start accepting answers when you get help.

Comment: Why is this question marked as a duplicate? I thought is took votes by 5 different people before a question gets closed?

Comment: @camickr: see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible approach...

I prefer to rely on the `TableCellRenderer`, but in this case, it's not going to be possible.

Instead, this uses the `getToolTipText` method of the `JTable` to try and load the image from the database based on the value of column `0`, which is assumed to be the ID of the image we are looking for.

This uses a caching mechanism so that instead of having to hit the database each time the tooltip is requested, it can look up any previously cached values.

```
public class MyTable extends JTable {

    private Connection con;
    private Map<Long, File> imgCache;

    public MyTable(Connection con) {
        this.con = con;
        imgCache = new HashMap<>(25);
        // Register with the TooltipManager
        setToolTipText("No image available");
    }

    @Override
    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent event) {
        String tip = super.getToolTipText(event);

        int col = columnAtPoint(event.getPoint());
        int row = rowAtPoint(event.getPoint());

        Object value = getValueAt(row, 0);
        if (value instanceof Number) {
            long id = ((Number) value).longValue();
            File source = imgCache.get(id);
            if (source == null) {
                try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select name, img from table where id=?")) {
                    ps.setLong(1, id);
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        String name = rs.getString("name");
                        Blob blob = rs.getBlob("img");
                        int blobLength = (int) blob.length();
                        byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
                        blob.free();
                        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
                        source = File.createTempFile(name, ".jpg");
                        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", source);
                        imgCache.put(id, source);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException | IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                    tip = "Failed to load image: " + exp.getMessage();
                }
            }
            if (source != null) {
                try {
                    tip = "<html><body>"
                                    + "<img src='"
                                    + source.toURI().toURL() + "'>";
                } catch (MalformedURLException exp) {
                    tip = "Failed to load image: " + exp.getMessage();
                }
            } else {
                tip = "No image available";
            }
        }
        return tip;
    }

}
```

Beware, if the cell renderer has a tooltip, it will override this value.