# Embed HTML in JAR with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, embedded-resource

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443315/is-it-possible-how-to-embed-and-access-html-files-in-a-jar) question, but still no luck.

I want to embed HTML pages with CSS files. In my project I have `res` folder, in `.classpath` I have `<classpathentry kind="src" path="res"/>` so that my files are embedded.

```
|-- src
|   `-- com
|       `-- pkg
|           `-- blahblahblah
|               `-- CTLiner.java
`-- res
    `-- html
        |-- index.html
        `-- style.css
```

`CTLiner.java` is main class file.

```
URL u = CTLiner.class.getResource("/html/index.html");
System.out.println(u.toURI().toString());
webView.showPage(u);
```

I use this code to load `index.html`. If I run this from Eclipse I get the following output

```
file:/home/user/workspace/CTLiner/bin/html/index.html
```

And

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Works great. And when I export project as Runnable JAR, code outputs:
    rsrc:html/index.html
And CSS file isn't found.

I believe that if I move `index.html` and `style.css` files up-tree (can I say so?) everything will work, but is there any other soltion?

Comment: Try to put it under src/main/resources?

Comment: @TungstenX works the same if I understood what you meants.

Comment: I found that it is easier to put it where your IDE/compiler wants it than to fight with it ;)  Have you looked at the content of the JAR file? (using winrar or winzip, etc)

Comment: Yep. If I do everything like I mentioned in the question, the `html` folder appears in the root of the JAR. I don't know how to check where it searches for `style.css`. Oh, wait. I know, gonna check.

Comment: @TungstenX It looks in the root of the JAR.

Comment: Thus index.html is in /html but styles.css is in / ?  The index.html is looking for it in its own directory, that is /html

Comment: I thought so too, buuut no. I have style in `/` and html in `/html/index.html`.

Finally solved. The problem was Library handling option in export menu. Going to post answer now =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the `Package required libraries into generated JAR`, but I had to use `Extract required libraries into generated JAR`. I don't know why yet.

When I used the `Package`method, java used to look for `style.css` in the root of the JAR file, no matter where the HTML file was located.

[image: Export menu]