# using html tables in java desktop application (with netbeans)

Tags: java, html, swing, jsp, netbeans

I have a java web JSP application, which I need to translate to a java desktop application, which I can distribute in a jar file.

I'm new to netbeans, and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to use html tables, instead of the JTable provided by netbeans.

The thing is that there's a lot of code in my jsp's that create these html tables, and I was wondering if I can re-use it with netbeans.

It has to be a desktop application, it shouldn't run on a web-browser.

I understand that you can't use html in a java desktop app, but if at least I could use just html tables, that would be a huge time saver for me.

I've been searching for the right answer for a couple of days, and still haven't found a concrete answer. Plus, when you say "table", Google thinks you're talking about a database table, which is not my case.

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: [`JEditorPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) can render HTML 3.2 with some extensions, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18443315/230513).

Comment: *"when you say "table", google thinks you're talking about a database table"* Add **-**ThingYouDoNotWant e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=html+table+-db

Comment: I have never tried a table, but you can [render some html in Swing components.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! both answers seems to be very helpful. I'll take a look to both of them see which one suits my needs better. I forgot to mention that I also need radio buttons, check boxes, text boxes and other html elements inside the html table. I hope they can render style-sheets as well

Comment: and yes, I used that "-" modifier, but still, I was getting a lot of database related results. Thanks for the tip anyway.