# Open html file located inside jar file

Tags: java

I have a little problem with a part of the code.
I have an offline version of my website inside my jar file, if the user needs help he can click on a button to open the HTML file where the software operations are explained.

In Eclipse it works fine when i use this lines if the help button is pressed :

`URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("assets/help/index.html");`

`Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());`

However in the jar it doesn't works, i know i should use :

(`getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath)`)

to get a resource located inside a jar file.
But this function returns an InputStream object, whereas I need a URI or URL object if I want to use the browse(URI uri) method.

Therefore how could I succeed to open this file?
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible/how to embed and access HTML Files in a JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443315/is-it-possible-how-to-embed-and-access-html-files-in-a-jar)

Comment: Is the file in the JAR? Under that path?