# Add image between text in JEditorPane

Tags: java, image, swing, jeditorpane

So I know how to insert an image in the JeditorPane in Java. But for example I would like to put the image between (for example) the 3 and 4 line of text in my Jeditorpane.

It's like in Gmail where you can edit your Signature and you can put some images in it..
What I am trying to do is an email service provider and I would also like to make my own Signatures...

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a HTML Editor with live previe:

[Ekit](http://www.hexidec.com/ekit.php) seems fairly light (160Ko in one jar, [source and jar here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ekit/files/))

[image]
<sub>(source: [hexidec.com](http://www.hexidec.com/images/ekit.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Set content type to `text/html` and [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29) will start rendering the assigned text as HTML. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573055/showing-images-on-jeditorpane-java-swing) explains how to put images. No third party library is necessary, unless you want to use HTML features above 3.2.

Comment: Wow this Ekit is really good. I hope that I will found what I am searching for. And as I sad I already know how to put an image in editor pane and I have content type text/html. What I don't know is how to add some images randomly between text where I want.
As I said I hope that I will find the answer in the source code of Ekit.