# Render a gif in java application using ImageIcon and Image classes

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gif, graphics2d

**What am I doing?**

A multiplayer 2D Videogame using sockets, finite state machine, jpanel, keylisteners, imageloader with hashtable and some other things.

The thing is that I want some gifs to render the player and enemies movements.

**What have I tried?**

- [How to draw a gif animation in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240328/how-to-draw-a-gif-animation-in-java)
- [Java Draw a GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924230/java-draw-a-gif?lq=1)

**How it looks right now**

The white rectangle is suppose to be the player, also I can render the HUD with some messages from the server

[image: videogame running]

Here is my code (I did not put all the code of the classes to avoid the fatigue of reading unnecessary things)

**MyGraphics class (The player and enemies will extend this class)**

```
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class MyGraphics extends JComponent{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected int x1;
    protected int y1;
    protected int x2;
    protected int y2;
    protected int height;
    protected int width;
    protected Image image;

    // Setters & getters are here
}
```

**Player class (The user plays with it)**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import Videogame.ImageLoader.ImageLoader;
import Videogame.Observer.Observer;
import Videogame.Observer.Subject;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Player extends MyGraphics implements Subject {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean isDead = false, falling = false, jumping = false, moving = false, standing = true;

    private ArrayList<Observer> obs = new ArrayList<>();

    public Player() {
        // Configure player characteristics
        setWidth(30);
        setHeight(50);
        setX1(20);
        setY1(600);
        image = ImageLoader.getInstance().getGif("playerIdle");
    }

    public static class SingletonHolder {
        private static Player instance = new Player();
    }

    public static Player getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.instance;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, x1, y1, width, height, null);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(x1, y1, width, height);
    }

    public void moveRight() {
        changeImage("right");
        this.setX1(this.getX1() + 3);
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        changeImage("left");
        this.setX1(this.getX1() - 3);
    }

    public void moveUp(){
        changeImage("up");
        this.setY1(this.getY1() - 3);

    }

    public void moveDown(){
        changeImage("down");
        this.setY1(this.getY1() + 3);
    }

    public void changeImage(String movement) {
        if (movement.equals("up")) {
            image = ImageLoader.getInstance().getGif("playerIdle");
        } else if (movement.equals("right")) {
            image = ImageLoader.getInstance().getGif("playerWalkingRight");
        } else if (movement.equals("left")) {
            image = ImageLoader.getInstance().getGif("playerWalkingLeft");
        } else if (movement.equals("down")) {
            image = ImageLoader.getInstance().getGif("playerIdle");
        }
    }
}
```

**ImageLoader (load and save images/gifs into hashtables)**

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Image;

public class ImageLoader {
    private Hashtable <String, BufferedImage> images;
    private Hashtable <String, Image> gifs;

    private ImageLoader(){
        this.images = new Hashtable<String, BufferedImage>();
        this.gifs = new Hashtable<String, Image>();
    }

    public static class SingletonHolder{
        private static ImageLoader instance = new ImageLoader();
    }

    public static ImageLoader getInstance(){
        return SingletonHolder.instance;
    }

    // Load images and gifs into their hashtables
    public void load(){
        try{
            // Menu backgrounds
            images.put("menu", ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("../Resources/Backgrounds/menu.png")));
            images.put("pause", ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("../Resources/Backgrounds/pause.png")));
            images.put("gameover", ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("../Resources/Backgrounds/gameover.png")));

            // In game backgrounds          
            images.put("fondo1", ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("../Resources/Backgrounds/fondo1.png")));
            images.put("fondo2", ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("../Resources/Backgrounds/fondo2.png")));

            // Player
            gifs.put("playerIdle", new ImageIcon("../Resources/Gifs/Player/Player.gif").getImage());
            gifs.put("playerWalkingRight", new ImageIcon("../Resources/Gifs/Player/WalkingRight.gif").getImage());
            gifs.put("playerWalkingLeft", new ImageIcon("../Resources/Gifs/Player/WalkingLeft.gif").getImage());

            // Boss
            gifs.put("FlyingLeft", new ImageIcon("../Resources/Gifs/Boss/FlyingLeft.gif").getImage());
            gifs.put("FlyingRight", new ImageIcon("../Resources/Gifs/Boss/FlyingRight.gif").getImage());
            gifs.put("FlyingUp", new ImageIcon("../Resources/Gifs/Boss/FlyingUp.gif").getImage());
            gifs.put("FlyingDown", new ImageIcon("../Resources/Gifs/Boss/FlyingDown.gif").getImage());
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Image getGif(String key){
        System.out.println("Gif to load: " + key);
        return gifs.get(key);
    }
}
```

**GamePanel (Has control over the animation)**

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{
     // Graphics
    private Graphics dbg;
    private Image dbImage = null;

    public GamePanel(GameContext gameContext){
        this.gameContext = gameContext;

        setBackground(Color.white);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PanelWidth, PanelHeight));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
        addKeyListener(GameKeys.getInstance());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        isRunning = true;
        while(isRunning) {
            this.gameUpdate();
            this.gameRender();
            this.paintScreen();
        }
    }

    private void gameRender() {
        if(dbImage == null){
            dbImage = createImage(PanelWidth,PanelHeight);
            if(dbImage == null) {
                System.out.println("dbImage is null");
                return;
            }else {
                dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
            }
        }
        gameContext.gameRender(dbg,PanelWidth,PanelHeight);
    }
}
```

**Play State (Has the logic of what to do when the state machine has current state of playing)**

```
import Videogame.Figures.Player;
import Videogame.HUD.HUD;
import Videogame.ImageLoader.ImageLoader;
import java.awt.*;

public class PlayState extends InGameState{
    @Override
    public void gameUpdate(){
        // Move level enemies, platforms, etc.
    }
    @Override
    public void gameRender(Graphics g, int PanelWidth, int PanelHeight){
        // Background
        background = ImageLoader.getInstance().getImage("fondo1");
        g.drawImage(background,0,0, PanelWidth, PanelHeight, null);

        // HUD details
        HUD.getInstance().render(g);

        // Player movement
        Player.getInstance().render(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void play(){
        // Nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void pause(){
        gameContext.setCurrentState(gameContext.getPauseState());
    }

    @Override
    public void gameOver() {
        gameContext.setCurrentState(gameContext.getGameOverState());
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: *"I did not put all the code of the classes to avoid the fatigue of reading unnecessary things"* Even reading 5 classes of code that cannot be put together and compiled, is tedious. 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Comment: BTW - is the GIF animated?

Comment: Sorry for being late with my response! My bad, I thought putting just those 5 classes would be understandable, but you're right, without an example it's harder to see how everything connects.

And yes, the gif is animated! I'll try to edit it, thx for the advice